# C++: how to convert string vector elements into unsigned char?

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

I have a string vector and a self declared type of unsigned char:

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
BYTE data[11];
```

I have assigned values to result. Now I want to copy the elements of `result` into `data`:

```
for ( int i=0; i<11; i++)
{
    data[i] = result[i];
}
```

But it gives out error, saying `No suitable conversion function from std::string to BYTE exists`.

How can I handle this?

**Update:**

First, thank you all for your precious comments and answers. 
In my code, my `result` is of six elements like these values:

```
0x30
0x31
0x32
0x33
0x34
0x35
```

I tried as Raxvan's answer, but at the end, `data` only captures the first value of those string elements, that is, all zeros. What I actually want to do is to let `data` have the same values as `result`, but of `BYTE` type, so that it is similar to assigning values like this:

```
BYTE data[] = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 } // this line works correctly
```

Comment: It is impossible in general case - because you have unknown number of unknown length strings, and try to put it all into a fixed-length 11-byte array

Comment: It doesn't make sense to convert a string (an arbitrary number of characters) into a single byte. What do you actually want in the `data` array?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> result;` is effectively a *two dimensional* array of characters, to get an individual character you must write `result[i][j]`. But `data` is *one dimensional*, that's where the problem lies. So probably the solution is either make `result` one dimensional, or make `data` two dimensional. Can't really help with that because I don't have the bigger picture.

Comment: Your `BYTE` is single character and to it's array (1D array) you are trying to store a 2D array.

Comment: Its true, and if you ditched the vector/array aspect entirely, and tried to assign just one single string to one single BYTE, you would find it also would not work. And then if you asked us why, we would wonder, "why is he trying to cram a a whole string into a single byte?". At which point we might also wonder if you meant BYTE to be a pointer to char, as in the way C tends to handle strings, cause that actually vaguely doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing your types.

The `data` is an array of BYTE (so basically able to hold 11 **characters**),
but `result` is an array of `string` (meaning it can hold multiple **strings**, each of those holding multiple characters).

So depending on what you actually need you can do two things:

If you need all strings to be converted into BYTE arrays, then create an array of arrays of BYTE:

```
// adapt sizes to your needs
size_t const MaxStrSize = 11; // allows to hold 10 characters (+ 0 delimiter)
size_t const MaxStrCount = 11;
BYTE data[MaxStrCount][MaxStrSize];

for (int j=0; j<MaxStrCount && j<result.size(); ++j)
{
    for ( int i=0; i<MaxStrSize && i<result[i].length(); i++)
    {
        data[j][i] = result[j][i];
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you only want to access one of the strings contained in the vector (e.g. the first one): See [Raxvan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285077/671366).

Answer (score 3):

`string` encapsulates an array of `char` and the compiler doesn't know how to convert that into one char. If you want to take the first character from the strings then you can do this:

```
for ( int i=0,j = 0; i<11 && j < result.size(); j++)
{
    if(result[j].size() != 0) //safety first.
        data[i++] = result[j][0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its long since I have written some CPP code, so kindly excuse for the syntax errors. 
I think what OP is trying to achieve is convert the 2D array to a single comma separated string.

Here is my sample code:

```
 char [] DATA = "";

        for ( int j = 0;j < result.count(); j++)
        { 
          if(j < result.count()-2)
          result = strcat(result, ",")
          DATA =       strcat(DATA, result);
        }
```